# removing apostrophes for plotting of matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am trying to plot a graph on matplotlib but it will not work properly as the values are returned with apostrophes, here is my code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
emp_data_list=[]

def read_file():
infile = open ('emp_data.txt', 'r')

for row in infile:
    if not row.startswith('#'):
        row = row.rstrip('\n').split(', ')
        emp_data_list.append(row)
infile.close()

read_file()


for item in range(len(emp_data_list)):
salaries = [stuff[4] for stuff in emp_data_list]
print salaries
```

i also used this for salaries aswell:

```
salaries = [salary for emp_no, name, age, pos, salary, yrs_emp in emp_data_list]
```

when salaries is printed it returns:

```
['29000', '24000', '42000', '21000', '53000', '42000', '50000', '33000', '38000', '22000', '19000', '23000', '44000', '32000', '28000']
```

i believe this is why my graph isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the strings to integers in the code below

```
salaries = [int(salary) for emp_no, name, age, pos, salary, yrs_emp in emp_data_list]
```

Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Mark this as the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The apostrophes which you see in your `print` output show up there to indicate that the values are strings. I guess you need to convert your variables to integers before plotting:

```
salaries = list(map(int, salaries))
```